# spring boot scanning and injecting external non-spring beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What does it take, or is it even possible for Spring to scan and inject non-spring annotated classes? For example.

resource.jar

```
com.project.resource.ResourceInterface
com.project.resource.StandardResource <-- concrete implementation

@Singleton <--- Standard CDI annotation
public class StandardResource implements ResourceInterface{
    @Override
    public void something(){}
}
```

Now let's say I have a spring boot application which depends on `resource.jar`.

com.project.resource.SpringApp

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.project"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringApp{
    ... initializer
    @Inject
    private ResourceInterface resourceService; <--- this is not found
}
```

Is this supposed to work out of the box? Is this even possible? I'm using spring boot `2.0.0.RELEASE`. I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'resourceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.project.resource.ResourceInterface' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
```

Thanks

Comment: `Singleton` and `Inject` are JavaEE annotations. For spring, you use `Autowired` to inject beans

Comment: as far as i understand the latest versions of spring recognize `@Inject` for injection. i was able to inject by placing a `@Named` annotation on my external beans but im not sure if spring handles `@Singleton` or `javax`'s `@Qualifier`s

Comment: try to remove Singleton and add `@Scope(value = "singleton")
@Component`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spring framework `@Singleton` has no meaning, as such even if class is picked up by component scanning it's going to be ignored. In order for Spring to recognize your class you can:

- Create a configuration class in com.project.resource with `@Bean` of
  `ResourceInterface` and instantiate it as `StandardResource`.
- Since you are using Spring Boot you can create Auto-configuration (which will be similar to the first option) in resource.jar. You can follow examples
  from [creating autoconfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html). With this approach no changes needed in com.project.resource

After that your spring boot app will run normally

Comment: i went with option #1 but i didnt hardcode `StandardResource`, i used spring's context to `getBean`. this way i can change which version is injected based on config/profiles